# Ansible instance not appearing on AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, console, ansible, instance

So I'm using Ansible on my MBP to try create key_pair and create/provision EC2 instances.  Playbook runs fine with no error but when I check AWS console there is no new key and no new instance... Ping to supposedly created Public IP times out so I am thinking something failed.  Ansible definitely hit AWS since if I disable the AWS access key then Ansible errors out, and not using the Ansible created key in the second task also fails so a key must have been created, just not uploaded to AWS?

Can you spot anything I did wrong?

```
Playbook yaml content:
- name: Create a sandbox instance
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    instance_type: t2.micro
    image: ami-d1315fb1
    region: us-west-1

  tasks:
    - name: Generate key
      ec2_key:
         name: ansible_key
         region: "{{ region }}"
         aws_access_key: #my_key
         aws_secret_key: #my_key
         state: present

    - name: Launch instance
      ec2:
         key_name: ansible_key
         group: default
         instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
         image: "{{ image }}"
         wait: true
         region: "{{ region }}"
         aws_access_key: #my_key
         aws_secret_key: #my_key
      register: ec2
    - name: Print all ec2 variables
      debug: var=ec2
```

Playbook runs fine with output being:

```
PLAY [Create a sandbox instance] ***********************************************

TASK [Generate key] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Launch instance] *********************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Print all ec2 variables]                 *************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ec2": {
        "changed": true, 
        "instance_ids": [
            "i-0898f09f8d3798961"
        ], 
        "instances": [
            {
                "ami_launch_index": "0", 
                "architecture": "x86_64", 
                "block_device_mapping": {
                    "/dev/sda1": {
                        "delete_on_termination": true, 
                        "status": "attached", 
                        "volume_id": "vol-04e9c4c4f5d85e60d"
                    }
                }, 
                "dns_name": "ec2-54-215-253-115.us-west1.compute.amazonaws.com", 
                "ebs_optimized": false, 
                "groups": {
                    "sg-778b5711": "default"
                }, 
                "hypervisor": "xen", 
                "id": "i-0898f09f8d3798961", 
                "image_id": "ami-d1315fb1", 
                "instance_type": "t2.micro", 
                "kernel": null, 
                "key_name": "ansible_key", 
                "launch_time": "2017-08-16T16:57:09.000Z", 
                "placement": "us-west-1b", 
                "private_dns_name": "ip-172-31-29-166.us-west1.compute.internal", 
                "private_ip": "172.31.29.166", 
                "public_dns_name": "ec2-54-215-253-115.us-west1.compute.amazonaws.com", 
                "public_ip": "54.215.253.115", 
                "ramdisk": null, 
                "region": "us-west-1", 
                "root_device_name": "/dev/sda1", 
                "root_device_type": "ebs", 
                "state": "running", 
                "state_code": 16, 
                "tags": {}, 
                "tenancy": "default", 
                "virtualization_type": "hvm"
            }
        ], 
        "tagged_instances": []
    }
}

PLAY RECAP     *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: are you sure, you have selected the `N.California` region from the console?

Comment: dang, you're right, didn't even see the Region toggle in the corner, more used to the DigitalOcean interface where all instances are listed at once

one related question though - the public ansible_key is up on AWS, but where is the private .pem key?  its not stored in the local folder or the ~/.ssh folder on the MBP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the few things:
- sure, you have selected the `N.California(us-west-1)` region from the console
- For private part of the key to store inside the `.ssh` under your username, do the following steps:

```
- name: Create an EC2 key
  ec2_key:
    name: "ansible_key"
    region: "us-west-1"
    aws_access_key: #my_key
    aws_secret_key: #my_ke
  register: ec2_key

- name: save private key
  copy:
    content: "{{ ec2_key.key.private_key }}" 
    dest: "/Users/{{lookup('env', 'USER')}}/.ssh/aws-private.pem" 
    mode: 0600
  when: ec2_key.changed
```

**Note:** Run this playbook from the scratch to create new key and save it into your `~/.ssh` directory.